# Nullable columns and model java classes

Tags: java, sql, database, types, model

Let's say I' have a table in a SQL DB with one or more nullable columns
wich have integer, boolean or other "primitive" (in java) values.

Is it a good approach to use primitive wrapper classes (such as Integer,Boolean etc) for the nullable fields in the model java classes
in order to be able to easily proagate null values into the nullable columns or there exist better strategies (I 'm pretty sure they do) ?

I hope this question is clear enough. :)

EDIT:

Example:
all the fields but dep_str_id can be null

```
 String insert =   
                    "INSERT INTO Department(dep_str_id , dimension ,type , description ) " +
                        "VALUES ('" + dep.getDepStrId() + "'," + 
                                      dep.getDim() + "," +
                                      dep.getFamily() + "," + 
                                      dep.getDescr() + ");";
```

thanks

Comment: but primitives types don't accept null value, how is one able to insert null values to the nullable columns in the db ?

Comment: Sorry, I was meant to say you should use wrapper classes.

Comment: Use wrapper classes and move on. Except for decimal values, don't use `Float` or `Double`, instead use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading, you can use the `ResultSet.wasNull()` method:

```
rs.next();
int i = rs.getInt(1);
if (rs.wasNull())
    i = 0;
```

If you are writing, you can use the `setNull()` methods, like:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = ...
pstmt.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

Comment: Yes but this way the DAO layer would have responsabilities it shouldn't have...or am I missing something ?

Comment: the setNull() and wasNull() methods are useful when you use primitives, because it's not possible to represente a null value with a primitive, but if you are working with String, or Date which can be null, you could use rs.getString(1) and get a null, or pstmt.setNull(1, myNullStringVar) without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You're starting this the wrong way around. The database is servant to the application. You should make your database do what the application needs and not invert the servant and the master.

This means when writing into the database you should make clear whether you allow NULL values or not. If you have something like a String, Integer or different non-primitive it's usually not advisable to force a `NOT NULL` constraint on the database.

OTOH, if you have actually *enforced* that the field cannot contain NULL in your application logic, you may as well mirror that in the database.

In short: There is no real best-practice to generalize this, but usually you'd not disallow NULL.